# How to understand the kth receive on a channel with capacity C happens before the k+Cth send from that channel completes？

Tags: go, channel, memory-model

It comes from [Channel communication](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7).

What I really can't understand is why kth receive happens before the **k+Cth** send? Why not **kth** send or **k+1** th send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capacity of a buffered channel is a number of *nonblocked* sends to the channel that can happen. When you have used all the capacity (**C + k** states about it) the next send will be blocked until a receive from the channel and only then it will complete.

If rephrase the sentence from the link with some numbers like **C = 3** and **k = 1** (for clarity), it will be like:
*"The fourth send to a channel with a capacity 3 will complete after the first receive from the channel"*.

Comment: Rephrasing to this sentence make it easier to understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The kth receive on a channel with capacity C happens before the k+Cth send from that channel completes.

It simply means that the channel with capacity c, can only hold c messages at a time thus to send **11th(k+c)** message on a channel with capacity of **4(c)**, **7(k)** messaged should have been received other wise the 11th send will be blocked until the receive.